# Trying to set z-index on WordPress side bar so the header overlaps

Tags: wordpress, z-index

I've been fooling around with z-index all over the place on this site.  What I want is to have the sidebar tucked underneath the curved header image.  Here's the WP site I'm working on: http://evansvillechamber.org/wordpress/  and here's how it looks in HTML and which I am trying to replicate: http://www.evansvillechamber.org/.  I tried setting the sidebar to a - z-index and the header and branding image both to high positive z-index, but nada.  Also tried moving the sidebar around in the index template.  Any other ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `position:relative` to line 165 of your style.css file and that should fix the problem.

screenshot

[image]

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, if the answer was satisfactory please don't forget to mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "position:absolute" to your element. Something like this:

```
#primary {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 720px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1999;
}
```

Please let me know if that works for you or not. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, no, the sidebar just disappears.  Tried applying  position:absolute; to various bits and bobs in the header.  These kind of worked, but then they overrode the #main area.  I think this is heading in the right direction though!

Comment: I just posted another answer above rather than commenting here. Hope that works! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try adding "position:absolute" to #branding and adding margins to #primary:

```
#primary {
    margin-left: 900px;
    margin-top: 25px;
  }


#branding {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2000;
}
```